# Can't run Synfig Stuido. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: synfig-studio

I installed it from repos. Thre 'Run Synfig' shortcut in menu, from terminal I can't run because it asks for 'sif' file and options.

Comment: No issues here with the command `$ synfigstudio` ... I.e. open "SynfigStudio", create something, and save it. Then you can run the saved file with `$ synfig [file]`

Comment: @Knud Larsen that's an answer, than you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Icon "Synfig Studio".

Or the command `$ synfigstudio` ... and the "SynfigStudio" GUI will open.
Then create something, and save it.

You can run the saved file with `$ synfig [file.sif*]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also right click Synfig icon on your desktop and then choose Preferences (or something like that) from the drop down menu. A window opens. There, choose the rightmost tab (it reads something like "access rights" or "privileges"). There you can simply cross a square to force Ubuntu to open Synfig as an application.